# How to call MyChecksum instead of KernelChecksum ( KernelChecksum assembly coded)

Tags: linux, kernel, arm, embedded-linux, neon

I have this typical requirement here:

There's a file in kernel `/arch/arm/lib/csumpartial.S` which has a function named `csumpartial()` which computes 16-bit checksum ( which obviously is assembly coded), and this function is exported with the EXPORT symbol.

I have now implemented the same function with NEON optimizations using intrinsics which is in a file named `csumpartial.c`

I have the following requirements:

1. Now I want my version of function 'csumpartial' to be called by the calling kernel functions instead of the assembly version.

   --To achieve this, should I replace the csumpartial.S file with my csumpartial.C file? But then how to replace ( what all things need to be taken care of)?
2. This csumpartial.c file should be compiled with a special compiler flags `-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -flax-vector-conversions -O3` for NEON optimization.

   -- So where and how to mention this compiler flag?

In short, the assembly version should be completely deprecated and the c version should be compiled with the `-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -flax-vector-conversions -O3` flags while the kernel is compiled. And the c version of the function should be called, when someone from kernel calls `csumpartial`

Early help would be much appreciated.

Few inputs:

1. Linux version 2.6.37
2. cross compiling for arm using cross compiler tools ( cgt_a8/arm-2009q1)
3. coding for ARM cortex-a8

Let me know for any more inputs

Note: Only I'll be using this edited kernel, so I understand the risks involved with such a replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this with a hack, here are the things I did to get it working:

Figured out two alternate ways to do this:

1. Replaced the `csumpartial.S` with `csumpartial.c` under `arch/arm/lib/` and since `csumpartial.c` contains NEON instructions and has to be compiled with special compiler flags, add this line to Makefile:

   `CFLAGS_csumpartial.o += -mfpu=neon -mfloag-abi=softfp -mflax-vector-conversions -O3`

   (in some case this shouldn't work, due to conflicting compiler flags to that of neon flags , during the compile time)

   we can filter out the conflicting compiler flags, by using `filter-out` function in the Makefile, but then we will have another issue that the filtered out flags wont be available for other files as well (since we want to negate out the compiler flags ***only*** for csumpartial file, so this will be a problem)

   so I figured out alternate way (2)
2. To be very clear, I did the following steps:

   a. Delete the csumpartial.S from `arch/arm/lib`

   b. Remove the `csumpartial.o` entry from the Makefile under this folder

   c. Create a new folder `neon` under `arch/arm/lib`

   d. add the `csumpartial.c` file here also create a Makefile and add this to the Makefile

   **arch/arm/lib/neon/Makefile**

   `KBUILD_CFLAGS += -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -flax-vector-conversions -O3`,

   as to negate the conflicting compiler flags during the compile time, use the following lines:

   `KBUILD_FLAGS := $(filter-out -compiler-flags-to-negate, $(KBUILD_FLAGS))`

   `lib-y := csumpartial.o`

   e. to the topmost Makefile i.e. `arch/arm/Makefile` add this `libs-y+=arch/arm/lib/ arch/arm/lib/neon/`

that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build the modified kernel just once - compile your *csumpartial.c* to *csumpartial.o* with required compilation flags from command line. After that compile your whole kernel. GNU make will NOT recompile *.S* to *.o* files with higher timestamps.

For a permanent solution: remove csumpartial.S, create your csumpartial.c, add the following lines to the */arch/arm/lib/Makefile*:

```
CFLAGS_csumpartial.o += -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -flax-vector-conversions -O3

# seems this line is not necessary
$(obj)/csumpartial.o: $(obj)/csumpartial.c
```

Comment: Thanks @clover, but I had already tried this, but see my answer for the issue I faced with this solution.